# How do I push an item from a parent component to an array inside a child component in a Vue 3 app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am making the transition from Vue's Options API to the Composition API and for this purpose, I have put toughener a small Todo App.

In `App.vue` I have:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="card">
      <Header />
      <List />
      <AddTodo @add-todo="addTodo" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue';
import Header from './components/Header.vue';
import List from './components/List.vue';
import AddTodo from './components/Add.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header,
    List,
    AddTodo,
  },

  methods: {
    addTodo: function (text) {
      let newTodo = {
        done: false,
        text: text,
      };

      if (text.length > 2) {
        console.log(newTodo);
        // this.todos.push(newTodo);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I `components/List.vue` I have:

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <Item
      v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
      @toggle-todo="toggleTodo(item, index)"
      @delete-todo="deleteTodo(item, index)"
      :item="todo"
      :key="index"
    />
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue';
import Item from './Item.vue';

export default {
  name: 'List',

  components: {
    Item,
  },

  setup() {
    const todos = ref([
      {
        text: 'Animi, odit facere.',
        done: true,
      },
      {
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit.',
        done: false,
      },
      {
        text: 'Dolor sit amet consectetur.',
        done: true,
      },
    ]);

    return { todos };
  },

  methods: {
    toggleTodo: function (item, index) {
      this.todos[index].done = !this.todos[index].done;
    },
    deleteTodo: function (item, index) {
      if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        this.todos.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

As you can see above, I have the `todos` array in the (to do) list component, as this make most sense. App.vue is a used (mainly) as a container for the other components.

In `components/Add.vue`, I have the form intended to add an item to the list of todos.

```html
<template>
  <form class="card-footer" @submit.prevent="$emit('add-todo', text)">
    <input type="text" v-model="text" />
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue';
export default {
  name: 'AddTodo',

  setup() {
    const text = ref('');
    return { text };
  },
};
</script>
```

Since the `todos` array is not inside `App.vue`, the line `this.todos.push(newTodo)`, that I have commented out, cannot work.

What I need is to push the `newTodo` object into the `todos` array of the (child) component `List.vue`. I have been unable to do that.

What is the easiest and most reliable way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Lift up `todos` state to the common parent, which is App, or use global store

Comment: @EstusFlask How do I lift up `todos` state to the common parent?

Comment: Pass todos as a prop to List instead, but you have to implement 'toggle' event instead of toggleTodo, the same way as in Add to avoid mutating a prop inside List . Global store is considerably more convenient for that, especially if there's only one "list" data per app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `todos` as props for your List component then bind it a list in parent component :

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="card">
      <Header />
      <List :todos="todos" @delete-todo="deleteTodo" @toggle-todo="toggleTodo" />
      <AddTodo @add-todo="addTodo" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from "vue";
import Header from "./components/Header.vue";
import List from "./components/List.vue";
import AddTodo from "./components/Add.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Header,
    List,
    AddTodo,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isValid: false,
      todos: [
        {
          text: "Animi, odit facere.",
          done: true,
        },
        {
          text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit.",
          done: false,
        },
        {
          text: "Dolor sit amet consectetur.",
          done: true,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleTodo: function ( index) {
      this.todos[index].done = !this.todos[index].done;
    },
    deleteTodo: function (index) {
      if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        this.todos.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
    addTodo: function (text) {
      let newTodo = {
        done: false,
        text: text,
      };

      if (text.length > 2) {
        this.isValid = true;
        this.todos.push(newTodo);
      } else {
        this.isValid = false;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In List component define todos props and emit the events to change the todos in parent :

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <Item
      v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
      @toggle-todo="toggleTodo( index)"
      @delete-todo="deleteTodo( index)"
      :item="todo"
      :key="index"
    />
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import Item from './Item.vue';

export default {
  name: 'List',
  props:["todos"],
  components: {
    Item,
  },

  methods: {
    toggleTodo: function ( index) {
      this.$emit('toggle-todo',index);
    },
    deleteTodo: function ( index) {
      this.$emit('delete-todo', index);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: It adds todos ok, but when I try do toggle an item, I ger the error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'done')`.

Comment: please recheck my edited answer, just remove the  item argument

Comment: you're welcome, I'll try